# What is a password mangler

Tags: passwords

What is the definition of a password mangler and what is its application used for? I've did some searches on it, but the information are quite vague.

Comment: in what context did you see this term?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a standard term. A quick search reveals that many different people use the term to mean many different things. The common element is that the process takes one password and modifies it.

Some uses are to make a weak password stronger, others are to enable you to use the same password everywhere but to have the mangler make it unique for each site.

So, I don't think there is a standard use, or even a standard use case, let alone a common definition.

Comment: This sounds similar to the "rules" functionality of the major password cracking tools (hashcat, John the Ripper, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A mangler is something that is juggled or juked. Password mangler is a term that defines a script that would juggle your password to make it stronger. Its like converting a string of characters of any length and mangle it, transforming upper-to-lower case, spaces to underscores, alphabets to digits and vice versa.  Let's take an example.

I have a password `thisismypassword` and I choose a password mangler to work on this. The mangler will convert the above password in various ways as per its configuration and set of rules. For example the password can be mangled to any of the following:

```
7h1515myp455w0rd
Th1$1$myp@$$wOrd
123thisismypassword321
7H1SiSmYp@5$w0rd
```

A mangler is always configured by a ruleset or what we know as a config file, where one can configure the different types of rules one wants to follow when creating a mangled list.

A few such tools which mangles passwords and creates a mangled password list are:

- [RSmangler](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/rsmangler)
- [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/presentations/Passwords12-Mangling-Rules-Generation/)

Comment: And, do not use these.  This just makes it harder to remember, and not much more difficult for a cracker like John to break.  https://www.xkcd.com/936/